# Compute $\sum_{k=1}^{22}\binom{21}{k-2}3^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I just got to a new material in discrete math and I still cant get a good grasp of the material, if anyone can solve this, it'd be much appreciated.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{22}\binom{21}{k-2}3^k$$

Comment: Is it supposed to include a term $$3\binom {21}{-1}$$

Comment: @abiessu What do you mean? I know that I need somehow to use $(a+b)^n$.. Which is $Sygma C(n,k)*a^(n-k)*b^k$ I guess..

Comment: The first term, with $k=1$, is it zero or non-zero?

Comment: @abiessu I believe that it is zero. we didn't study with $C(n,negative value)$

Comment: @Ilan: $\binom{n}k$ is defined to be $0$ if $k<0$ or $k>n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So I can define $ j = k - 1 $ and start with zero till 22

Comment: @Ilan: You can, but in this case it’s actually more useful to set $j=k-2$, as in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Let $\ell=k-2$, so that $k=\ell+2$, and rewrite the summation:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{22}\binom{21}{k-2}3^k=\sum_{\ell=-1}^{20}\binom{21}\ell3^{\ell+2}\;.$$

Now $\binom{21}{-1}=0$, so this is

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{20}\binom{21}\ell3^{\ell+2}=9\sum_{\ell=0}^{20}\binom{21}\ell3^\ell\;.\tag{1}$$

To finish, use the binomial theorem to evaluate

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{21}\binom{21}\ell3^\ell\;,$$

and then make any necessary adjustments to get the value in $(1)$.

Comment: I will go study it properly now and come solve that last question you got me. and post the solution and accept your answer. thx!!

Comment: @Ilan: You’re welcome! Leave a comment when you’ve posted your solution, and I’ll take a look at it.

Comment: $\sum_{\ell=0}^{21}\binom{21}\ell3^\ell\; = (1+3)^{21}$ but how do I go to $(1)$ now?

Comment: @Ilan: The summation in $(1)$ is just missing one term, the $\ell=21$ term; you know the value of that term, so you subtract it from your $4^{21}$ (and of course then multiply the result by $9$).

Comment: But, what do I substract from $4^{21}$? to get to $L=20$

Comment: @Ilan: Your sum has a term for each $\ell$ from $0$ through $21$; the sum in $(1)$ has a term for each value of $\ell$ from $0$ through $20$. Thus, it’s missing the $\ell=21$ term. What is that term in your sum?

Comment: It is $C(21,21) * 3^{21}$ ?

Comment: @Ilan: That’s right. And $\binom{21}{21}=1$, so it’s just $3^{21}$.

Comment: thank you for letting me think! Engineering is opening my head. thank you so much!

Comment: @Ilan: You’re very welcome!