# Compute$\sum_{k=2}^{n+5}\frac {1}{k(k-1)}\binom {n+1}{k-2}2^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Compute$\sum_{k=2}^{n+5}\frac {1}{k(k-1)}\binom {n+1}{k-2}2^k$ .

Well, here how I tried and got stuck:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1{k(k-1)}\binom{n+1}{k-2}&=\frac{(n+1)!}{k(k-1)(k-2)!\big((n+1)-(k-2)\big)!}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+3-k)!}\\
&=\frac1{(n+3)(n+2)}\cdot\frac{(n+3)!}{k!(n+3-k)!}\\
&=\frac1{(n+3)(n+2)}\binom{n+3}k\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+5}\frac1{k(k-1)}\binom{n+1}{k-2}2^k=\frac1{(n+3)(n+2)}\sum_{k=2}^{n+5}\binom{n+3}k2^k\;.$$

Now use the binomial theorem and make a couple of adjustments, a bit like what you did in [the previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569327/compute-sum-k-122-binom21k-23k).

Comment: Well, if I do $L = K - 2$ I have a problem here. I can't get to a $(a+b)^n$ result

Comment: @Ilan: There’s no need to change the index this time: you already have it as both the lower number of the binomial coefficient and the exponent on the $2$. The $k=n+4$ and $k=n+5$ terms are automatically $0$, so you can let the sum run from $k=2$ to $n+3$. Suppose that instead it ran from $k=0$ to $n+3$? Could you evaluate it then?

Comment: So it will go from$ C(n+3,2)*2^2 + C(n+3,3)*2^3 + ... + C(n+3,n+3)*2^{n+3}$ . but what then? how can I evalute it to $(a+b)^n$ from here?

Comment: @Ilan: Start by evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^{n+3}\binom{n+3}k2^k$, much as you did in the previous problem; then subtract the $k=0$ and $k=1$ terms, since they don’t appear in the summation that we’re really dealing with.

Comment: so, from $k=0$ to $n+3$ it will be, $(1+2)^{n+3}$. then, i have to substract$ (1 + 2*(n+3)$ from $3^{n+3}$?

Comment: @Ilan: That’s right. And then just multiply by the fraction out in front of the summation, and you’re done.

Comment: Yey! I hope on the exam I will be able to think out of the box like that. I need to compute more exercises like this. I'll be uploading one more soon. I need some rest with gym now :) Thank you very much Brian!

Comment: @Ilan: You’re most welcome. (A bit of gym sounds like a good idea at this point!)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^{n+5}\frac {1}{k(k-1)}\binom {n+1}{k-2}2^k&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+3}\frac {1}{(k+2)(k+1)}\binom {n+1}{k}2^{k+2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac {1}{(k+2)(k+1)}\binom {n+1}{k}2^{k+2}\\
f(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac {1}{(k+2)(k+1)}\binom {n+1}{k}x^{k+2}\\
f'(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac {1}{k+1}\binom {n+1}{k}x^{k+1}\\
f''(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom {n+1}{k}x^{k}=(1+x)^{n+1}\\
f'(x)&=\frac1{n+2}(1+x)^{n+2}+C_0\\
f'(0)&=0 \rightarrow C_0=-\frac1{n+2}2^{n+2}\\
f(x)&=\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}(1+x)^{n+3}-\frac1{n+2}2^{n+2}x+C_1\\
f(0)&=0\rightarrow C_1=-\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}2^{n+3}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac {1}{(k+2)(k+1)}\binom {n+1}{k}2^{k+2}&=f(2)\\
&=\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}(1+x)^{n+3}-\frac1{n+2}2^{n+2}x-\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}2^{n+3}\\
&=\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}3^{n+3}-\frac1{n+2}2^{n+3}-\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}2^{n+3}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

with the work above i have got $${\frac {27\,{3}^{n}-2\,n-7}{ \left( n+3 \right)  \left( n+2 \right) }}$$

Comment: I agree with this solution, but in general I do not type in the end result ... could you please say why you did so here? :-) this is just to learn more on how the game is played here :-) many thanks.

Comment: simplify the last terms above